# Index number of a Specific word in the Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to find the occurrence of a specific word in the document.

for example, consider a document with 2500 words and the word which i want to find is 400th word in the document, result should be 400. I found the this result using looping through the document words.. is there any other way of doing this without loop, as, if my word is present in last paragraph of the document, it takes time to find the occurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes the solution for you... But please keep in mind the followings:

1) results are return to Immediate Window

2) I provided two options of getting position of words- `Words.Count` include all punctuation marks whilst `ComputeStatistic`, which is probably more suitable for you, will return real position of the word within 'real words collection'.

```
Sub PositionOfTheWord()


    Dim WordToSearch As String
        WordToSearch = "hendrerit"

    Dim FirstWordFound As Range
    Set FirstWordFound = ActiveDocument.Content
        FirstWordFound.Find.Execute (WordToSearch)

    If FirstWordFound.End <> ActiveDocument.Content.End Then
        Debug.Print "Word on position: " & ActiveDocument.Range(0, FirstWordFound.End).Words.Count
        Debug.Print "Word on position: " & ActiveDocument.Range(0, FirstWordFound.End).ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)

    Else
        Debug.Print "There is not search word within ActiveDocument"
    End If

End Sub
```